# NSThread.callStackSymbols behaves differently on .ipa

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

On debug, "NSThread.callStackSymbols" returns an array with full stack info but on Adhoc or Release I get little / no data.

Can anyone explain this behaviour because in some part(s) of my code I have to determine the caller of a method, or is there an alternative to this.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you have code that needs to look at the call stack to determine some specific behavior then you are doing it all wrong.

Comment: @maddy - I use this to determine the caller of a method (i.e. the class and method which triggered a call to another method).

Comment: I understand that. I'm saying that there is no reason you should be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your app for App Store it is in Release mode which means no debugging symbols are being generated.

If you want to get the same info as when you were testing, you simply need to go to XCode's Product menu -> Scheme -> Edit and chose 'Debug'.